# How to interpret Output - Browser log? What is the exact error cause in code below? Am I using old angular.min.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is the Markup I picked up (for angularjs practice / learning) from: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Collapse (ui.bootstrap.collapse) which I pasted in my index.html

```
<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
                <hr>
                <div collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div> 
                </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the corresponding javascript I picked up from: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Collapse (ui.bootstrap.collapse) which I pasted in my app.js

```
function CollapseDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
}
```

Below is the Output- Browser log displayed in my Netbeans IDE:

```
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CollapseDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.10/ng/areq?p0=CollapseDemoCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:8383/bmw/js/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (public_html/js/angular.js:1553:11)
    at assertArgFn (public_html/js/angular.js:1563:3)
    at http://localhost:8383/bmw/js/angular.js:7278:9
    at http://localhost:8383/bmw/js/angular.js:6662:34
    at forEach (public_html/js/angular.js:327:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (public_html/js/angular.js:6649:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (public_html/js/angular.js:6106:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (public_html/js/angular.js:6697:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (public_html/js/angular.js:6106:15) (05:34:11:286 | error)
```

Comment: The important part is "Not a function, got undefined", which means that the controller `CollapseDemoCtrl` wasn't found. Are you sure your JavaScript file is loaded? Good tip: use the unminified AngularJS version for development.

Comment: @Blackhole, Yes I am sure the JavaScript file is loaded.

Comment: @Blackhole,  CollapseDemoCtrl in my app.js is underlined green and the mouse over shows "Unused"

Comment: Now using Unminified AngularJS version.

Comment: When you declare your controller as above, the function CollapseDemoCtrl needs to be declared in the global namespace, are you doing that in your app.js? Also, you might try the stable version of Angular (1.2.16). I'd be surprised if this basic functionality was broken in the beta, but you never know...

Comment: Yup need to have angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("CollapseDemoCtrl", function($scope){$scope.isCollapsed=false}); //or something of the sort

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are declaring ng-app somewhere in a parent element (i.e. body or div tag that surrounds your controller). See jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Fn4rL/14/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed =!isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
        <hr/>
        <div ng-show="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
function CollapseDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
}
```

Comment: I already have ng-app declared in <body>. I think the problem is in app.js where CollapseDemoCtrl is underlined green and the mouse over shows "Unused".

Comment: Could you post your app.js file?  This is likely where the issue is occurring.